# How to add two char arrays with contents being number?

Tags: java

I was wondering how one would go about adding the contents of two char arrays.
For example,

```
char[] a = {1,2,3}
char[] b = {1,2,3}
//the output should be c  
char[] c = {2,4,6}
```

I know this isn't proper coding, but I need to know how this would be done.

Comment: What would be the result of `{3, 4, 5} + {5, 6, 7}`?

Comment: Just use a loop? I get the feeling this is a homework question.

Comment: {3, 4, 5} + {5, 6, 7} would be (9,1,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is most likely a learning exercise, here are some pointers to have it completed:

- `char`s that represent digits are numeric constants representing UNICODE code points from `'0'` to `'9'`, inclusive.
- To get a value of a digit from a `char` value, subtract `'0'` from it, like this: `int digitA = a[i] -  '0';`
- To add two "numbers", start at the back of each number, and go backward to the front in a loop
- Keep a "carry" value, which is zero or one, depending on the result of the addition being less than ten or greater than ten
- On each step, add `digitA` to `digitB`, and add `carry` to the sum.
- Make a carry for the next operation by comparing the sum to ten.
- Take the last digit of that sum by applying `sum % 10` to the result.
- Make the digit of the result by adding `'0'` to `sum % 10`, and put it into the result
- Note that the result array may be longer than the longest of the two arrays in case there is a `carry` from the highest digit.
- You need to maintain three indexes in your loop - one for the result, and two for each of the two numbers
- You wouldn't know if you need an extra digit for the result, so it may be easier to allocate space for an extra digit upfront, and then remove it if it ends up zero.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over both arrays and add the results

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] a = new char[] {1,2,3};
    char[] b = new char[] {1,2,3};
    char[] sum = new char[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        sum[i] = (char)((int)a[i] + (int)b[i]);
}
```

Obviously, there are a lot of edge cases here that are no good.  But this is the most direct answer to the question I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

For your question I took the liberty of writing a  proper code of what I got from your question.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        char[] a = {1,2,3};
        char[] b = {1,2,3};
        char[] c = {0,0,0};
        for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
            c[i] = Character.forDigit(a[i]+b[i],10);
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }

    }
}
```